# what are the jquery UI plugins suited for new web developer?

Tags: jquery

i'm looking for good `jquery` plugin library for **web UI**. 
i'm new to web development and there are so many plugin libraries out there such **jqwidget** but **jqwidgets** is a comprehensive set of the plugins so it seems complicated. are there any **jquery UI plugins** like **jqwidget** but not so complex like **jqwidget** but has all types UI controls? the controls also should be able to communicate with ASP MVC technologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/ - jQuery UI is a curated set of user interface interactions, effects, widgets, and themes built on top of the jQuery JavaScript Library.